# ICD-10 Variable recoding

Tags: r, dplyr

I should do some recoding on a database.
It is a medico-administrative database (so a large database). I should recode the diagnoses that are coded (ICD-10). I take the example on the database above just as an indication.

```
ID<-(1:15)
Diag<-c("A001","A002","A003","A004","B001","B002","B003",
      "C001","C002","C003","C004","C005","C006","C007","C008")
Age<-round(rnorm(15,25,10))
DATA<-data.frame(ID,Diag,Age)
```

So I would like to:

code as "Disease 1" all modalities of "Diag" that begin with "A" and "B".

code the modalities from C001 to C004 as "Disease 2".

code the modalities from C005 to C008 as "Disease 3".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DATA %>%
   mutate(new = case_when(str_sub(Diag, 1, 1) %in% c('A', 'B') ~ 
        'Disease 1',
      Diag %in% str_c('C00', 1:4) ~ 'Disease 2', 
      TRUE ~ 'Disease 3'))
#   ID Diag Age       new
#1   1 A001   9 Disease 1
#2   2 A002  37 Disease 1
#3   3 A003  27 Disease 1
#4   4 A004  31 Disease 1
#5   5 B001  22 Disease 1
#6   6 B002  23 Disease 1
#7   7 B003  30 Disease 1
#8   8 C001  38 Disease 2
#9   9 C002  24 Disease 2
#10 10 C003  25 Disease 2
#11 11 C004  33 Disease 2
#12 12 C005  26 Disease 3
#13 13 C006  45 Disease 3
#14 14 C007  20 Disease 3
#15 15 C008  22 Disease 3
```